# QuickFix /N application randomly getting stuck / hanging at SendRaw Function

Tags: quickfixn

I have a simple c# window forms application that uses QuickFix/n to connect to our broker. This sits on a W2012 server and occasionally executes orders.

Sometimes it will be absolutely fine and run for hours on end and sometimes it hangs totally randomly. The program is totally unresponsive, cant click anywhere, move the window, total lack of control. Unfortunately no errors are thrown etc

Ive used dottrace to find out where the program is stuck and it shows it is stuck (or stuck in an infinite loop) in the QuickFix.Session.SendRaw method

I don't call SendRaw explicitly anywhere in the code, could any QuickFix gurus weigh in with any ideas what could be going on here?

Thank you

Comment: Just to be sure: are you running the latest version of QuickFIX/N?

Comment: I am running 1.7, however Ive been using this for the past 3 years and never had an issue, all of a sudden its started doing this! Only reason I have avoided upgrading is because it has worked flawlessly before.

Comment: `SendRaw` is eventually called from within `Send`.  However, hard to say why it would hang, unless dottrace can be more precise within the function.  Probably a good time to upgrade to the latest version.  I don't expect you would have much trouble doing that; I've tried pretty hard to avoid changing the interface.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Grant, I have upgraded to 1.10 and it ran flawlessly for 2 hours and then did the exact same thing! Is there anyway to get some kind of log or more information to where the problem is, as you say dottrace finishes at sendraw and doesnt give me anymore clues! Thanks again